Unusual Querystrings Appearing In IIS Requests
I have had some performance issues on my web server lately, with irregular load times, and I have gone to the IIS Page Request Monitor and the command line appcmd list request .  Being new to these tools, this video was very helpful .
There, in the results from both Request Monitor and appcmd list request, I see mostly one page numerous times with "unusual" querystrings (they have a combination of unencoded and encoded HTML characters).
For example, the correct URL is:
/directory/bill-smith?purchase_page=2&inventory_page=3

while the incorrect one that may appear (or variations thereof - some with %3F, some with %3D, etc):
/directory/bill-smith?purchase_page=2%3Finventory_page=3%3Fpurchase_page=4&inventory_page=1

The actual page number value in the string varies, as does the general randomness of the seeming concatenation of the string.  Some are quite a bit longer.
As I am pretty new to IIS Page Request Monitor (and the command line
appcmd list request

I was wondering if the page requests returned are only page requests that have some sort of problem processing, or if it is all page requests that are returned?
I noticed that most listings returned involve the Rewrite Module, but I'm not sure if that's coincidental in relation to the unencoded characters and the concatenation, or if the characters are somehow creating an extra load on the Rewrite Module and server?
Would there be a good 'next step' in this troubleshooting to determine if the character encoding is the culprit, or if it might be some sort of random "attack"?
Thanks

The IIS Request Monitor and appcmd list request command show requests that are either in process or taking longer than usual, as described in this document. Since you see query string URLs in the list, these requests might be experiencing issues during processing.
Regarding the URL Rewrite rule, I recommend using Failed Request Tracing (FRT) to track how the rewrite rules are affecting your requests. This will help determine if the rule is looping or altering query strings.
To check if these requests are part of a potential attack, examine your IIS logs to see if they originate from specific IP addresses. You can mitigate such attacks by enabling IIS IP and Domain Name Restrictions.
If the query strings are longer than expected, they might be consuming extra resources. Set limits on URL or query string length in your IIS configuration to avoid performance issues. You can find more information on limiting query strings in this guide.

Thanks very much.  This is very helpful.
I just had a few questions about your points.

Regarding the querystrings that appear in the GUI Worker Processes>Requests, I am not seeing any of those in Failed Tracing.  Admittedly, there are alot of xml files in the Failed Tracing folder.  I've just been opening each xml file as it appears and then analyzing it.
Would there be an easier way of viewing the exact request in both the app cmd and failed tracing, perhaps an ID?  I do see the number after "REQUEST" in the app cmd.  Thanks.


The website is now running with faster load times, although I cannot pinpoint exactly what may have led to the improvement.  There are still a few worker process entries in the Requests queue of IIS; however, the particular page listed there does load without any of the odd characters in the querystring.
